# bearer token only works when browsing site without "www."

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an `ASP.NET Core 3.0, Angular, IdentityServer4` application deployed to IIS. Which is using a server certificate exported to .pfx for token signing. (This same certificate is used for the SSL certificate but from the certificate store).

The application loads fine both as `https://www.example.com` and `htts://example.com` (no SSL errors).

**However** when browsing on `https://www.example.com` and trying to access data on any endpoints requiring authorisation, it doesn't work. The following error is observed in the response header:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://www.example.com' is invalid"
```

I'm not sure where to start looking... will this be an IdentityServer4 configuration issue?

---

FYI, this project was developed from the template project created by `dotnet new angular -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual`.

Answer (score 0):

The token issuer (which is the origin of the site that issued the token) is a part of the contract between an OIDC provider and the clients and APIs that rely on it.

`identityserver4` by default will use the incoming request details to determine what the value of `iss` should be in any tokens it issues.

As such you should usually only use a single host name for your OIDC provider - e.g. identity.example.com or something along those lines.

Another option may be to force it to use a pre-defined host name rather than determining it based on the request.